# set an event to locked

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to insert a new event that is 'locked': no more modifications for major fields like:  "summary", "description", "location", "start", "end" or "recurrence" as said on the API site: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource
However, after the event appears on the calendar, I can still modify it.
Anybody here worked with "locked" events? pls help me out.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same situation: I was trying to insert a locked event using a service account with API v3 but it did not work. So, after some research, I found this explanation and realized that locking a "master copy" event is not possible.
As stated here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/whats-new

> The locked flag for events indicates that the main event fields ("summary", "description", "location", "start", "end", or "recurrence") cannot be changed. Attempts to do so are rejected with a 403 Forbidden response. This can only be set for attendees' copies of an event, never for the organizer (i.e. the master copy). Other event details, such as extended properties, can still be changed. This is not the same as "guestCanModify: false", which indicated that modifications aren't reflected on copies other than the user's. This field is read-only.